# Scraping HTML Source with Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, web-scraping, intel-xdk

I want to build a mobile app using the Intel XDK. The app needs to get data from the HTML source of other websites and process it. Is it possible to scrape this data using the Intel XDK? Or is there another (javascript) tool which I could use to achvieve this? Is it even possible to do this with a HTML5 mobile app due to the limitations of the Same-Origin-Policy?

The important point here is, that I want to scrape the site directly on the device where the app runs, without the need of an additional webserver that is running in the background.

Comment: Please leave a descriptive comment why you downvote, at least. Then I would try to improve the question. Thank you.

Comment: The reason that the question is downvoted is because it shows no attempt to solve the problem.  You need to show your current code and say what the specific problem with it is.  This is not a site to have others code for you.

Comment: @Anonymous I am not asking for code! I just want to know if it is even possible or if there is a plugin/framework/whatever that can help to achieve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this can be done with [XmlHttpRequests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).